# how to edit user input in a .ser file (serialization)

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, user-input, edit

I'm making a program for a library system. The user can put a book in a library(ser file) and save it. But now I want to be able to edit the data the user has just entered.

For example, I ask them to give an id, a name, an author and a price for the book. I want to be able to edit any of these fields by asking the user to enter the id of the book they would like to enter, then they would simply show up one by one on the screen again and require the user to input the field data again. I'm using a switch statement to take the user input and go from there. How would I go about editing the data already entered in a .ser file?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (running) { // while running is set to true the while will run
        System.out.println("Enter 0 to load a library"
                + "\nEnter 1 to save and quit"
                + "\nEnter 2 to list all books in library"
                + "\nEnter 3 to add book to library"
                + "\nEnter 4 to edit a book in the library");

        int answer = userInput.nextInt();   //  takes the answer and stores it in user input

        switch (answer) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Enter file name to load"); // choose which library to load                                                              
            fileName = userInput.next();

            loadScript(fileName);
            break;

        case 1: // case to save and quit
            saveAndQuit();
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println(lib.toString());
            break;

        case 3:
            addBook();
            break;

        case 4:
            edit();
            break;

        } // close switch

    } // end while

    System.exit(0); // exits program once while loop is done
} // end main
```

There are two other classes, a library and a book class although I dont think you would need to see them. This is the code I'm using to addd a book, I assume you could just mix this up a bit?

```
    public static void addBook() {  //  this method will add a book to the library
    int id;
    double price;
    String title, author;

    System.out.print("\nEnter book id: ");
    id = userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.print("\nEnter book title(one word/use _ for space): ");
    title = userInput.next();

    System.out.print("\nEnter book author: ");
    author = userInput.next();

    System.out.print("\nEnter book price: ");
    price = userInput.nextDouble();

    Book b = new Book(id, title, author, price);
    lib.addBook(b); // adds the book to the library

} // end addBook method
```

Comment: Why don't you deserialize and make your changes?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with serialization. How would I do that? Do I even need serialization? I was told by a friend I would!